# app isn't working on new device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an app that works on the Samsung S7 and the Tribute.  I recently tried it on the Samsung S5 and it crashed.  I get this:

```
 [ 11-19 13:08:57.067  3463: 4039 D/         ]
                                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9e587a40, tid 4039
11-19 13:08:57.156 3463-4039/com.example.android.pneumoniaapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-19 13:08:57.156 3463-4039/com.example.android.pneumoniaapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-19 13:09:02.117 3463-3463/com.example.android.pneumoniaapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-19 13:09:02.118 3463-3463/com.example.android.pneumoniaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.pneumoniaapp, PID: 3463
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                                    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.pneumoniaapp.Main_Activity.Recordbutton(Main_Activity.java:148)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It crashes when I hit the record button.  The button records auditory information using audioRecord and the accelerometer.  On the Tribute and SAMSUNG S7 the entire code works without a hitch.

```
public void Recordbutton(View view) {

    if (recordbuttonstatus) {
        playBtn.setEnabled(true);
        recordbuttonstatus = false;
        startBtn.setText(getString(R.string.stoprecording));
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        Thread accelerometerrecord = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run(){
                File accoutputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "accelerometervals.txt");
                try {
                    accoutputFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    writer = new FileWriter(accoutputFile, false); /*When false, the file is overwritten, when true, the file is appended.*/
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG2, "failed");
                }
            }
        });

        accelerometerrecord.start();

        Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();

                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

                    int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplingFreq,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                    short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

                    AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                            samplingFreq,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            minBufferSize);

                    audioRecord.startRecording();

                    while (!recordbuttonstatus) {
                        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
                            dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    audioRecord.stop();
                    dataOutputStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        recordThread.start();

    } else {
        startBtn.setText(getString(R.string.newrecording));
        recordbuttonstatus = true;
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelListener);

    }
}
```

Comment: `RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed`... `Main_Activity.java:148` What line is that?

Answer (score 0):

Check `AndroidManifest.xml` for these permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in your activity handle run time permission for marshmallow.

```
  private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Check for Record Audio permission and Write External Storage Permission before writing file on SD card.

```
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CODE);
         }else {
       //Write Data to SD Card
    }
```

and override `onRequestPermission` method of activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
          switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE: {
                 if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       this.finish();
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is required.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
        return;
    }
    default:
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        break;

       }
```

Comment: I have both of the permissions.  My phone's USB configuration is PTP because MTP doesn't work with Android studio.  The problem lies in something in my record code.  There must be a method that is not recognized in Android 6.01.